# all hyperbolic cyclic subgroup of P$SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ are Fuchsian.

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that all hyperbolic cyclic subgroups of $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ are Fuchsian.

Let $\Gamma$ be a hyperbolic subgroup of $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$. It is enough to show that $\Gamma$ is discrete, since all discrete subgroups of $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ are Fuchsian.

My aim was to do this by contradiction.

Assume $\Gamma$ is not Fuchsian. This implies there exists a sequence $\{T_k\}$ with $T_k \in \Gamma$ and $T_k \rightarrow Id$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

From here I don't know where to go, but surely I will have to use the fact that every hyperbolic element $T \in\Gamma$ has two fixedpoints, say $z_1, z_2$.

Comment: I don't see where your proof has used the hypothesis that $\Gamma$ is cyclic. And you have to use that hypothesis, because it is *false* that every hyperbolic subgroup is Fuchsian: take, for example, the subgroup $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} t & 0 \\ 0 & 1/t \end{pmatrix} \mid t > 0\right\}$.

Comment: thanks, I know that cyclic is necessary, but I don't know how to use this fact. should I use the fixed points of the  $T \in \Gamma$ which generates the whole $\Gamma$?

Comment: It's easy, but the difficulty might be sensitive to your choice of definition of "hyperbolic cyclic subgroup".

Comment: @YCor which definition would you suggest?

Comment: It's your own question, so I expect you have one in mind.

Comment: @Livpez. I am currently working on this proof and am in the same position as you. I am trying to find a way to show that the hyperbolic cyclic subgroup is discrete. Is it possible to somehow assume that the hyperbolic cyclic subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is non-elementary?

Comment: @math189925 I did not try this. I think it might be easier to show that $\Gamma$ acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{H}$. But I still need to try this.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea by finding some sequence $\{T_k\}$ which converges to the identity.
How to do this, you have to recall that we can conjugate any hyperbolic elements to $z\mapsto \lambda z$ for $\lambda≠1$.

For more detail see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326399/every-hyperbolic-and-parabolic-cyclic-subgroup-of-psl2-mathbbr-is-fuchsia/3327027#3327027).